# LINQ to Entities: Why can't I use Split method as condition?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities, split

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var aKeyword = "ACT";
var results = from a in db.Activities
              where a.Keywords.Split(',').Contains(aKeyword) == true
              select a;
```

Keywords is a comma delimited field.

Everytime I run this query I get the following error:

**"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."**

What is the alternative for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Please, there is really no reason to compare the result of a boolean operation with true. Just use the returned bool.

Comment: Obviously...I did it this way because I was using LINQ and it didn't like the Contains on its own either!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In response to your performance considerations on a big dataset:

You are going to be doing non indexed wildcard string matching on the client, so yes, there will be performance loss.

Is there a reason why you have multiple keywords in one table field? You could normalize that out, to have a ActivityKeywords table where for each Activity you have a number of Keyword records.

Activities(activity_id, ... /* remove keywords field */) ---> ActivityKeywords(activity_id, keyword_id) ---> Keywords(keyword_id, value)

Check out Non-first normal form: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

EDIT: Also even if you were to stick with the one column, there is a way to do everything serverside (if you have a strict syntax: 'keyword1, keyword2, ..., keywordN'):

```
var aKeyword = "ACT";
var results = (from a in db.Activities
              where a.Keywords.Contains("," + aKeyword) || a.Keywords.Contains(aKeyword + ",")
              select a;
```

Comment: It was really just for ease of use. Most activities will only have a few keywords hence I didn't see the need for another table for it. however, I never actually thought of doing what you have suggested...it would probably be a change for the better! Thanks.

Comment: I do have a strict syntax for the keywords and it is as you suggested i.e. Keyword, Keyword, Keyword. However, I decided to go with the other table. Thanks.

Comment: Pretty smart. But be careful guys, always trim your property before compare

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that LINQ-to-Entites has to translate everything you give it into SQL to send to the database.

If that is really what you need to do, you'll have to force LINQ-to-Entities to pull back all the data and LINQ-to-Objects to evaluate the condition.

Ex:

```
var aKeyword = "ACT";
var results = from a in db.Activities.ToList()
              where a.Keywords.Split(',').Contains(aKeyword) == true
              select a;
```

Be aware though, that this will pull back all the objects from the Activities table.  An alternative may be to let the DB do a bit of an initial filter, and filter down the rest of the way afterwards:

```
var aKeyword = "ACT";
var results = (from a in db.Activities
              where a.Keywords.Contains(aKeyword)
              select a).ToList().Where(a => a.KeyWords.Split(',').Contains(aKeyword));
```

That will let LINQ-to-Entities do the filter it understands (string.Contains becomes a like query) that will filter down some of the data, then apply the real filter you want via LINQ-to-Objects once you have the objects back.  The ToList() call forces LINQ-to-Entities to run the query and build the objects, allowing LINQ-to-Objects to be the engine that does the second part of the query.

Comment: @James - yes, the former will cost you quite a bit of performance.  The latter less so (it'll require a table/index scan, but will only return candidate rows).  If this is something you'll be running a lot of, I'd recommend storing the keywords in the DB pre-split (ie. a table with one row per keyword per activity -- Yannick's suggestion).  Then, you can write it as a query the DB can handle well.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I have decided to use Yannick's suggestion!

Comment: When using this approach I would suggest to just do two matches, so all the processing still happens server-side:
where a.Keywords.Contains("," + aKeyword) || a.Keywords.Contains(aKeyword + ",")

Comment: @Yannick - that won't take care of everything -- it'll still match keywords that begin with/end with the keyword in question, and you'll want to also add || a.Keywords == aKeyword.  You'll still need the post-filter.  Still, a separate table is the real way to go.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the way you are calling Split.  It should take an array.  Maybe there is another Split in Linq it is finding and giving you an unusual error:

This works for Linq to Objects:

```
 var dataStore = new List<string>
                    {
                        "foo,bar,zoo",
                        "yelp,foo",
                        "fred",
                        ""
                    };
 var results = from a in dataStore
               where a.Split(new[] {','}).Contains("foo")
               select a;

 foreach (var result in results)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Match: {0}", result);
 }
```

Outputs the following:

```
Match: foo,bar,zoo
Match: yelp,foo
```

Actually, thinking about it, do you need the split at all?  `a.Contains("foo")` may be enough for you (unless you don't want to hit `foobar`).

Comment: Yeah defo need the split (as you mentioned) keywords can be part of other keywords. Need an exact match.

Comment: Thanks Ray, you made me realise I can leave out the split!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to [look at this question about L2E and .Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities) for a solution that should be more efficient than guessing at a superset before filtering client side.