# How to split string in c# linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this

```
from d in db.v_Report_CompanySearches
orderby d.InquiryLogID descending
where (mPersonName == null || d.AccountName.ToLower() == mPersonName || d.PersonName.ToLower() == mPersonName) && 
      (mCompanyName == null || TagsContain(d.CompanySearchTerm, mCompanyName)) && 
      d.CreateDT >= mFrom && d.CreateDT <= mTo
select (d);
```

and

```
private bool TagsContain(string terms, string val)
{
    string[] tags = terms.ToLower().Split(';');
    return tags.Contains(val.ToLower());
}
```

but it crashes with `not supported error`. I think it's because I'm using a custom function `TagsContain`. How can I do that function in linq without custom stuff?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities: Why can't I use Split method as condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354723/linq-to-entities-why-cant-i-use-split-method-as-condition)

Comment: The duplicate is good, however it wont pick up a list with one element and unless its terminated by the seperator

Comment: Any solution will merely patch up poor design: you should split the tags in the database as a 1:n relationship. This is never going to work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Id `TagsContain` isn't supported by EF and have an underlying SQL function, it will crash. That's exactly what is happening here.

This however, should work:

```
from d in db.v_Report_CompanySearches
orderby d.InquiryLogID descending
where (mPersonName == null || d.AccountName.ToLower() == mPersonName || d.PersonName.ToLower() == mPersonName) && 
      (mCompanyName == null || d.CompanySearchTerm.Contains(mCompanyName)) && 
      d.CreateDT >= mFrom && d.CreateDT <= mTo
select (d);
```

Comment: I get this `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/string-canonical-functions `split` is not a supported function

Comment: @Saruman you're correct! I thought I double checked that, in hindsight though, just .Contains("SearchWord") should work

Answer (score 0):

Provider not able convert your custom function the sql. And I afraid split is one of the functions which not supported for generating sql.

You can use it without `.Split`

```
var query = 
    db.v_Report_CompanySearches
      .Where(report => report.CreateDT >= from)
      .Where(report => report.CreateDT <= to);

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(personName) == false)
{
    query = query.Where(report => report.AccountName.ToLower() == personName || 
                                  report.PersonName.ToLower() == personName);
}

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(companyName) == false)
{
    query = query.Where(report => report.CompanySearchTerm.StartsWith($"{companyName};") ||
                                  report.CompanySearchTerm.Contains($";{companyName};")) ||
                                  report.CompanySearchTerm.EndsWith($";{companyName}"))
}

var result = query.OrderByDescending(report => report.InquiryLogID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

What Fabio said is right. Split function of c# can not be converted into SQL query. So, you have one way here

Get all the values from DB into C# List object and then apply the split filter over it.

```
var myListObject = (from d in db.v_Report_CompanySearches
orderby d.InquiryLogID descending
where (mPersonName == null || d.AccountName.ToLower() == mPersonName || d.PersonName.ToLower() == mPersonName) && 
      d.CreateDT >= mFrom && d.CreateDT <= mTo
select (d)).ToList();
```

Then

```
var afterFilterObject = myListObject.Where(d => (d.mCompanyName == null || TagsContain(d.CompanySearchTerm, mCompanyName))).ToList();
```

Method to be called

```
private bool TagsContain(string terms, string val)
{
    string[] tags = terms.ToLower().Split(';');
    return tags.Contains(val.ToLower());
}
```