# LINQ query for tag system: Matching any of several tags?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, tags

I am just getting started with LINQ. I am creating an Entity Framework app that uses the canonical `Post` and `Tag` model. A `Post` contains an `ID`, `Text`, and `Tags`, and a `Tag` contains an `ID`, a `Name`, and `Posts`.

A [previous thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730272/linq-query-for-tag-system-search-for-multiple-tags) showed me how to query for a `Post` that matches *all* `Tag` objects (A *and* B *and* C) in a search list. But how would I query for a `Post` that matches *any* `Tag` (A *or* B *or* C) in the list? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumbled over the answer right after I posted this question. [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to the rescue!

Here's my code, which uses `PredicateBuilder`. It is set up as an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<Note> WhereContainsAnyTags(this IQueryable<Note> notes, IEnumerable<Tag> searchTags)
{
    // Initialize
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Note>();

    // Select Notes that contain any search Tags
    foreach (var searchTag in searchTags)
    {
        var tag = searchTag;
        predicate = predicate.Or(note => note.Tags.Any(t => t.Id == tag.Id));
    }

    // Set return value
    return notes.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
}
```

And here is how I call the code:

```
searchResults = m_ViewModel.ObjectContext.Notes.WhereContainsAnyTags(m_ViewModel.SearchTags);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work or not, but worth a try anyway I guess if you are already using `WhereIn`.

```
var posts = context.Tags.WhereIn(tag => tag.Name, acceptableValues)
                        .SelectMany(t => t.Posts);
```

The `WhereIn` should give you all the tags that are part of the name, and the `SelectMany` should give you all the posts containing those tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could aslo do it like this with Entity SQL

```
var post = ctx.Posts.Where("it.Tags.Id IN (1,2,3)");
```