# entity framework multiple many to many queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple model for security where there are:

- Users
- Roles
- Paths

and many to many links between these tables, so a user to roles, and roles to paths. I am trying to write a function so that from a username and a path it will return a bool value based on whether the user has access to that path. How can I do this with the entity framework? I currently have:

```
var rolesForUser = _entities.Users
         .Include("Roles")
         .Where(u => u.Login.Equals(username))
         .Select(u => u.Roles);

if(rolesForUser.Count() == 0) return false;

var authentications = _entities.WebPaths
         .Where(p => p.Path == path)
         .WhereIn(p => p.Roles, rolesForUser);

return (authentications.Count() > 0);
```

which uses an extension method [WhereIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities), however this can only compare on primatives so this doesn't work at the moment. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do it with [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Off the top of my head:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<WebPath>();
foreach (var role in from roles in rolesForUser 
                     from r in roles.Role
                     select r)
{
  predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.roles.Any(r => r.Id == role.Id));
}

var authentications = _entities.WebPaths.AsExpandable()
         .Where(p => p.Path == path)
         .Where(predicate);
return (authentications.Count() > 0);
```

Comment: Hi Craig, just had a go with this and on the line: "predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.roles.Any(r => r.Id == role.Id));" I am not able to access role.Id as role is a System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection object rather than a System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<roles>. I guess this is due to how I am selecting within rolesForUser though I'm not sure how to get it to come back as this.

Comment: What is the *exact* type (with parameters) of `rolesForUser`?

Comment: (local variable) IQueryable<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<roles>> rolesForUser

Comment: Oh, I see. You have a list of lists. I took a stab at flattening it in the edit.

Comment: Thanks Craig this looks like it's cracked it. I'm going to have a go at making this simpler if I can but this has answered the question. I had to change the line "from r in roles.Role" to be "from r in roles" but other than that it worked.