# Finding what methods a LINQ provider supports

Tags: .net, linq, custom-linq-providers

I just tried to use `Contains` in an Entity Framework query only to have it fail as this method doesn't exist in EF. However the code compiles which is frustrating.

Does anyone know how to find which methods a LINQ provider supports, given any LINQ provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really any API (that I'm aware of) that will tell you this, unfortunately.

If you're looking for an equivalent in EF, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities) might help you.

The examples in that question might also help to explain why it's not so easy to determine which expressions can be used with which providers - a lot of the logic actually resides in the extension method, not the provider.  Anyone can write an extension method on `IQueryable<T>` - it would be impossible for a provider to know whether an extension method that hasn't been written yet is going to work.  And `Contains` is just another extension method.