# Entity LINQ on many-to-many got error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains..."

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables (Users and Roles)  they are mapped as Many-to-Many in relational db. When I imported to Entity Data Content, they are still staying as the same relationship.

Since they are mapped as Many-To-Many in Entity,  I can access

```
Users.RoleCollection 
or
Roles.UserCollection
```

However, when I execute this LINQ query, I got "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains... method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

```
var result (from a in Users
            from b in Roles
            where a.RoleCollection.Contains(b)
            select a);
```

I think I must did something wrong... please help.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: No, that's a different use case for `Contains` (that question uses a `List`, as opposed to part of the L2E query. @Nix is correct here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use any....

```
     where a.RoleCollection.Any(x=>x.ID==b.ID)
```

or

```
     where a.RoleCollection.Any(x=>x==b)
```