# Problem with Contains

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities, contains

I have a little problem which i can't solve.
I want to use an SQL-In-Statement in Linq. I've read in this Forum and in other Forums that I have to use the .Contains (with reverse-thinking-notation :-)).
As input i have a List of Guids. I first copied them into an array and then did something like that :

```
datatoget = (from p in objectContext.MyDataSet
             where ArrayToSearch.Contains(p.Subtable.Id.ToString())
             select p).ToList();
```

datatoget is the result in which all records matching the Subtable.Id (which is a Guid) should be stored.
Subtable is a Detail-Table from MyData, and the Id is a Guid-Type.
I've tried several things (Convert Guid to String, and then using .Contains, etc),
but I always get an Exception which says :

'Linq to Entities' doesn't recognize the Method 'Boolean Contains(System.Guid) and
is not able to Translate this method into a memory expression. 
(Something like that, because I'm using the German Version of VS2008)

I am using L2E with .NET 3.5 and am programming in C# with VS 2008.

I've read several Examples, but it doesn't work. Is it perhaps because of using Guid's instead of strings ?
I've also tried to write my own compare-function, but I don't know how to integrate it so that .NET calls my function for comparing.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: Robert is correct this is a duplicate for 3.5, but also 4.0 directly suppports `Contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an `Any()` on the `arrayToSearch`?

```
 datatoget = objectContext
              .MyDataSet
              .Where(p => arrayToSearch.Any(i => i == p.Subtable.Id.ToString()) 
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try these two approaches:

First approach: don't convert anything. This assumes that p.Subtable.Id is defined as a GUID in the database.

```
Guid[] guids = GetGuids();

var dataToGet = (from p in objectContext.MyDataSet
                 where guids.Contains(p.Subtable.Id)
                 select p).ToList();
```

Second approach: convert all the GUIDs to strings first.

```
string[] guids = GetGuids().Select(g => g.ToString()).ToArray();

var dataToGet = (from p in objectContext.MyDataSet
                 where guids.Contains(p.Subtable.Id.ToString())
                 select p).ToList();
```

If neither of these approaches work, then we probably need to see more info about the problem, such as the schema of the database, the shape of the entities, etc.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for spending your time upon my question. The Link from Robert Havery made it :)
As I can see the .Contains() doesn't work (well) with Linq for Entities and .NET3.5.
There is no possibility to do it without writing an Extension Method.
I've tried a little bit with LinqPad and when using Linq 2 SQL, no problem with .Contains(). It did it as promised. And with Linq to Entities there was no promise, except that I always got the Exception (but this is also a promise :)).

So special thanks to Robert Havery, and all others who helped me.

Comment: You *can* do it with an extension method in 3.5, as Robert's link demonstrates.