# How do you implement the equivalent of SQL IN() using .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

In .net (c# or vb) expressions, how would you implement SQL's handy IN() functionality?

i.e. value in (1, 2, 4, 7)

rather than:

value = 1 or value = 2 or value = 4 or value = 7

Comment: what version of the .NET framework?

Comment: I mainly use 3.5. Not sure if there's anthing in 4.0 that makes this easier?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

static class SqlStyleExtensions
{
    public static bool In(this string me, params string[] set)
    {
       return set.Contains(me);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if (Variable.In("AC", "BC", "EA"))
{

}
```

Comment: params makes the call really neat.

Comment: Generic version - public static bool In<T>(this T me, params T[] List)

Answer (score 15):

I have made an extension method for this that I find quite useful. However, it is not much more than syntactic sugar wrapping the existing IEnumerable.Contains() function.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns true if the value is represented in the provided enumeration.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the value</typeparam>
/// <param name="obj">The object to check if the enumeration contains</param>
/// <param name="values">The enumeration that might contain the object</param>
/// <returns>True if the object exists in the enumeration</returns>
public static bool In<T>(this T obj, IEnumerable<T> values) {
    return values.Contains(obj);
}
```

Edit:
Someone beat me to it, damnit.
I'll keep by post here though since it's a more generic version.

Comment: wasatz - i've posted a version below that's extended to full expression and lambda functionality. might be nice to try it as an alternative if you're using any IQueryables

Answer (score 8):

```
if((new int[] {1, 2, 4, 7}).Contains(value))
{
    // Do some work.
}
```

As others have pointed out, you could create an In() Extension method (I'll keep it generic so you can use it on any type):

```
public static bool In<T>(T this obj, IEnumerable<T> col)
{
    return col.Contains(obj);
}
```

So the initial example becomes:

```
if(value.In(new int[] {1, 2, 4, 7}))
{
    // Do some work.
}
```

Comment: There is no `Array.Contains` method.

Comment: @Conrad - It exists as part of the LINQ Enumerable extension methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx

Answer (score 8):

I know there are LOADS of answers here, but here's my take on the subject, used daily in SubSonic. it's an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereIn<T, TValue>(
                this IQueryable<T> query,
                Expression<Func<T, TValue>> selector, 
                params TValue[] collection) where T : class
{
    if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
    if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    ParameterExpression p = selector.Parameters.Single();

    if (!collection.Any()) return query;

    IEnumerable<Expression> equals = collection.Select(value =>
       (Expression)Expression.Equal(selector.Body,
            Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));

    Expression body = equals.Aggregate(Expression.Or);
    return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p));
}
```

and WhereNotIn:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereNotIn<T, TValue>(
                this IQueryable<T> query, 
                Expression<Func<T, TValue>> selector, 
                params TValue[] collection) where T : class
{
    if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
    if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    ParameterExpression p = selector.Parameters.Single();

    if (!collection.Any()) return query;

    IEnumerable<Expression> equals = collection.Select(value =>
       (Expression)Expression.NotEqual(selector.Body,
            Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));

    Expression body = equals.Aggregate(Expression.And);

    return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p));
}
```

usage:

```
var args = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
var bookings = _repository.Find(r => r.id > 0).WhereIn(x => x.BookingTypeID, args);
// OR we could just as easily plug args in as 1,2,3 as it's defined as params
var bookings2 = _repository.Find(r => r.id > 0).WhereIn(x => x.BookingTypeID, 1,2,3,90);

var bookings3 = _repository.Find(r => r.id > 0).WhereNotIn(x => x.BookingTypeID, 20,30,60);
```

this really makes me smile every time i review it :)

jim

**[edit]** - originally sourced from here on SO but modified to use iqueryable and params:
['Contains()' workaround using Linq to Entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 7):

Or using `System.Linq`...

(VB.NET)

```
Enumerable.Contains({1, 2, 4, 7}, value)
```

or

```
{1, 2, 4, 7}.Contains(value)
```

(C#)

```
Enumerable.Contains(new int[]{1, 2, 4, 7}, value);
```

or

```
new int[] {1, 2, 4, 7}.Contains(value);
```

Comment: Just this: `{1, 2, 4, 7}.Contains(value)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Contains() method on the list.

```
    int myValue = 1;
    List<int> checkValues = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

    if (checkValues.Contains(myValue))
        // Do something
```

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ

```
var q = from x in collection
        where (new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 7}).Contains(x.value)
        select x
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will do many lookups on the same dataset it is good from a performance perspective to use `HashSet<T>`.

```
HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 4, 7 };
bool is5inSet = numbers.Contains(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some simple Linq with some pseudo code. No need to re-invent the wheel.

```
int[] values = new int[]{1, 2, 4, 7};
int target = 2;
bool contains = values.Any(v => v == target);
```

Or use `.Contains` as some have suggested.