# Select many rows from a data store using Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

We need to accept a collection of key values from user input. Then a query must be performed on a L2E data store which shall select all rows whose keys are included in the collection. The best I've got so far is:

```
var lines = dataStore.Entities.ToList(); /* To List to force a query */
var selectedLines = lines.Where(line=> inputValues.Contains(line.key)).Distinct();
```

However, this seems seems wasteful since we're pulling the entire data store in order to select (probably) just a small number of rows. Would it be less wasteful to execute a separate query matching each key value (the column is indexed) or is there a better way with Linq syntax that I've missed?

Comment: Why do you force the query to be executed? Is there a requirement behind this?

Comment: @thekip: Yes, there is. Unless the query is forced, L2E tries to render the .Contains method in to an expression and fails. I'm still waiting for a response back as to the L2E version so I can respond to the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF4 has support for `contains` so you can just use it directly.

```
var selectedLines = dataStore.Entities
                             .Where(line=> inputValues.Contains(line.key))
                             .Distinct();
```

For possible workarounds in earlier versions see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities).

Answer (score 0):

You should have the contains within your first query. 
This will then only return the values that the user specifiec. 
I would also recomend you look at [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) very nice tool and it shows you what queries are being create by Linq to Entities.

```
var lines = (from p in dataStore.Entities
            where inputValues.Contains(p.key)
            select p).ToList();
```