# Using StringCollection specified in Application Settings in a LINQ-to-Entities Query

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, settings, stringcollection

In my application, I have Property Setting which is of type String.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection. It contains a list of customer codes such as MSFT, SOF, IBM etc. I'm trying to use this in a Linq-to-Entities query in the where clause:

```
var ShippedOrders = dbcontext.Orders
 .Where(s=>(s.Status.Description.Equals("Shipped") && !Properties.Settings.Default.CustomersToExclude.Contains(s.CustomerCode)));
```

This fails as Contains is not recognized by Linq-to-Entities with a message similar to:

"LINQ-to-Entities does not recognize the method Contains...."

How do I revise the code above to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is tagged as C# 4 use a `List<string>` instead (`StringCollection` is ancient) and your query should work. Also you should resolve your list reference outside your query:

```
List<string> customersToExclude = ..
var ShippedOrders = dbcontext.Orders
                             .Where(s=>(s.Status.Description.Equals("Shipped") 
                                    && !customersToExclude.Contains(s.CustomerCode)));
```

**Edit:**

Just copy your customers to an array and use that:

```
var customerstoExclude = new string[Properties.Settings.Default.CustomersToExclude.Count];
myProperties.Settings.Default.CustomersToExclude.CopyTo(customerstoExclude, 0);
```

Comment: But List is not an option in the Type drop down in Project Properties -> Settings. That is where I get my list to exclude from.

Comment: @FMFF: You could just copy to a string array in that case, see update

Answer (score 17):

A shorter path is

```
myProperties.Settings.Default.CustomersToExclude.Cast<string>().Contains(blah);
```

That's a  handy trick for any situation where a collection isn't inherently LINQ-aware.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities). EF4 apparently supports Contains directly, though, so that'd be my prefered solution... :)