# Linq Expression building for Entity Framework involving complex object

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities, expression

I am using Entity Framework version 4.  I need to compare a large (~1 million record) SQL Server table to a longish (~2000) array of complex objects returned from a web service.  Five different properties need to be compared to determine whether an instance of the complex object is already in the database.

I created a function that returns an expression for use in .Where and .Any methods.  It looks like this (where A is the complex object, and tblA is the EF class):

```
function Expression<tblA, bool> GetSearchPredicate(A a)
{
    return ta => ta.Field1.Equals(a.Field1) 
        && ta.Field2.Equals(a.Field2)
        && ta.Field3.Equals(a.Field3)
        && ta.Field4.Equals(a.Field4)
        && ta.Field5.Equals(a.Field5);
}
```

This works.  And I can compare all 2000 instances of A by doing this:

```
IEnumerable<A> objects = [web service call]; 
var result = objects.Select(a => !db.tblA.Any(GetSearchPredicate(a)));
```

That works, too.  But it's slow.  So I looked into building a utility method that could build an expression that could be transmitted down to the database directly through EF.

I used the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities) as a basis for building that utility method.  The example in that question shows comparing a single property to a series of constants, while my version would have to compare multiple properties to multiple constants.  My best effort is below:

```
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereIn<TEntity>
       (
        this ObjectQuery<TEntity> query,
        IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> predicates
       )
    {
        if (predicates == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicates");

        IEnumerable<ParameterExpression> p = predicates.Select(pred => pred.Parameters.Single()).ToArray();

        IEnumerable<Expression> equals = predicates.Select(value =>
            (Expression)value.Body);

        Expression bigEqual = equals.Aggregate((accumulate, equal) =>
            Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));

        var result1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(bigEqual, p.First());
        var result = query.Where(result1);
        return result;
    }
```

This would be invoked like this:

```
IEnumerable<A> objects = [web service call]; 
var result = db.tblA.WhereIn(objects.Select(a => GetSearchPredicate(a)));
```

What I get is a message saying that "ta" (the placeholder for the TEntity object) is not bound.  I thought this was because I had multiple expressions (the variable `predicates`) being combined, and maybe this message was being thrown because I was only passing the parameter from the first of the `predicates` IEnumerable. But this happens even if `predicates` is one expression long.

I am reasonably sure, based on the method I linked to, that I could build an expression comparing each of the five properties to a constant (the values of `A.Field1` through `A.Field5`), rather than passing in the parameter `predicates` that already has them assembled into a series of expressions.  But I would rather not, since that would require my method to know that it's working with types `A` and `tblA`, and that's the opposite of generic and general-purpose.  (It'd also be complex and messy.)

I hope the examples I've shown explain what I want to do.  Can it be done in a generic way?

Comment: At what point do you get the message?

Comment: @GregBair  When I attempt to execute the result of the function.  Sorry, I left that part out!

Comment: Not trying to be unhelpful, but this would be pretty trivial to do (and very fast) with a stored procedure which you could import into your EF model. Do you have a particular reason not to do it that way?

Comment: @SteveWilkes  Thanks for your response.  Were you visualizing 2000 calls of a stored procedure that receives 5 parameters, or a stored procedure that took an XML parameter containing all 2000 instances?  The former didn't strike me as much faster, and the latter ... well, I've been considering it.  But I do want to know whether the kind of combining of expressions I want to do is possible anyway, just for my own knowledge.

Comment: I'd imagine the latter approach, yeah. Fair enough with regards to knowledge, I'd just want to be as lazy as possible and follow the path of least resistance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to replace the parameter in the predicate bodies with a single parameter. Something like this should work:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildOr<T>(
   IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> predicates)
{
    Expression body = null;
    ParameterExpression p = null;
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> first = null;

    foreach (Expression<Func<T, bool>> item in predicates)
    {
        if (first == null)
        {
            first = item;
        }
        else
        {
            if (body == null)
            {
                body = first.Body;
                p = first.Parameters[0];
            }

            var toReplace = item.Parameters[0];
            var itemBody = ReplacementVisitor.Transform(item, toReplace, p);
            body = Expression.OrElse(body, itemBody);
        }
    }

    if (first == null) 
    {
       throw new ArgumentException("Sequence contains no elements.", "predicates");
    }

    return (body == null) ? first : Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, p);
}

private sealed class ReplacementVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private IList<ParameterExpression> SourceParameters { get; set; }
    private Expression ToFind { get; set; }
    private Expression ReplaceWith { get; set; }

    public static Expression Transform(
       LambdaExpression source, 
       Expression toFind, 
       Expression replaceWith)
    {
        var visitor = new ReplacementVisitor
        {
            SourceParameters = source.Parameters,
            ToFind = toFind,
            ReplaceWith = replaceWith,
        };

        return visitor.Visit(source.Body);
    }

    private Expression ReplaceNode(Expression node)
    {
        return (node == ToFind) ? ReplaceWith : node;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        return ReplaceNode(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        var result = ReplaceNode(node);
        if (result == node) result = base.VisitBinary(node);
        return result;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (SourceParameters.Contains(node)) return ReplaceNode(node);
        return SourceParameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == node.Name) ?? node;
    }
}
```

Your `WhereIn` method then becomes:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereIn<TEntity>(
   this ObjectQuery<TEntity> query, 
   IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> predicates)
{
    if (predicates == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicates");

    var predicate = BuildOr(predicates);
    return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: WOW.  Awesome!  I will try this immediately!

Comment: It turns out that doing it the way I was trying results in many, many parameters to the RPC call, probably (I would guess) from all the instances of `A` whose property values I was passing.  But this solved the problem I was trying to solve.  Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems like we should be able to aggregate the expressions into a single expression using LINQ Aggregate.  Any thoughts on that, Richard?

Comment: @pomeroy: Unfortunately not. You need the visitor to replace the parameter from the subsequent expressions with the parameter from the first expression. Otherwise, you'll get an `InvalidOperationException` when you try to use the expression. *(variable 'a' of type 'type' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined)*