# How to Select Multiple records & Insert in other table using LINQ to Entity in WPF using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a **GridControl** which contains the List of items with Checkbox control in it.

I am adding & removing the ID to custom `List<int>` which contains the checked item column ID value. Now, i wan to loop through the `List<int>` and select the record from Table and by fetching these checked item want to insert in other table using **Linq** to Entity in **WPF** using **C#**.

```
List<Infill> infillList = new List<Infill>();
List<int> infillListIDs=new List<int>();
private bool ProcessItem(bool IsChecked)
        {
            bool result = false;
            Infill item = grdInfillInner.FocusedRow as Infill;
            if (IsChecked)
            {

                if (item != null)
                {
                    // DO STUFF HERE EXAMPLE ADD or REMOVE Item to a list, BASED on CHECKED or UNCHECKED!!!
                    int infillid = item.InfillID;
                    infillListIDs.Add(infillid);
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                if(infillListIDs.Contains(item.InfillID))
                {
                    // if uncheked the checked item then remove from custom list
                    infillListIDs.Remove(item.InfillID);

                }
            }
            grdInfillInner.FocusedRowHandle = -1;
            return result;
        }

private void BtnInsert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Total Items :" + infillListIDs.Count);
            //Insert the record in other table (having same table structure)
            //here by selecting from infillListIDs custom list of type List<int> 

        }
private void CheckEdit_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = ProcessItem(true);

        }

        private void CheckEdit_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = ProcessItem(false);
        }
protected void GetAllInfills()
        {
            List<Infill> infillList = new List<Infill>();
            infillList=BLL.GetAllInfills();
            if (infillList != null)
            {
                grdInfill.ItemsSource = infillList;
                grdInfill.GroupBy(grdInfill.Columns["Glass.GlassType"], ColumnSortOrder.Ascending);
                grdInfill.GroupBy(grdInfill.Columns["Glass.Glass_Description"], ColumnSortOrder.Ascending);
                grdInfill.AutoExpandAllGroups = true;

            }
        }
```

I want to fetch the records from **infill** table where **infillListIDs** containing **IDs** of all checked rows from **Infill** table and `insert into DummyInfill` table having same structure when insert button is clicked!

Answer (score 0):

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15829249/265100

Get the objects that have matching IDs and add to the new table.

```
Using (DB _db = new DB()){
  foreach(Infill inf in InfillCol){
    DummyInfill.Add(inf);
  }
  DummyInfill.SaveChanges();
}
```

I don't know what version of EF you are using but l understand that you can implement SQLBulkCopy.
See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610014/265100