# Using Contains method within linq's Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity

I've got a problem with my query.
I have two simple classes. Let's say

```
public class A{
  public List<B> MyCollection{get; set;}
}
public class B{
 public string Id;
}
//I want to do something like that
var myB = new B{Id="1"};
context.A.Where( x=> x.MyCollection.Contains(myB)).ToList();
```

How can I solve this? I know that I could do something like

```
context.A.ToList().Where...
```

but that's not the good idea, especially that I have few thousands records.

UPDATE!
context is a EntityFramework context and context.A represents DbSet 
I'm still getting error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains"
also I can't use

```
context.A.ToList().Where(....
```

because I have thousands of records and it will be to inefficient

Comment: `context.A.Where(x=> x.MyCollection.Contains(myB))`, unless I'm misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: Well, the problem is I couldn't get to that list as 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Boolean Contains...'.

Comment: @Matthew: disabling ToList() won't help because I need to get this QUeryable element to list or something enumerable

Comment: is `context.A` just a single instance of `A`, or is it an enumeration itself?

Comment: It's  DBSet<A> (Entity Framework)

Comment: What's the problem with my first comment?

Comment: It doesn't work. I can't initialize it to IEnumerable so I can't get those elements. Your soulution is like writing select and not firing it

Comment: put a `.ToList()` on the end, this will force EF to execute the statement it generates, otherwise it's deferred until something else enumerates it.

Comment: and that's what I did! context.A.Where( x=> x.MyCollection.Contains(myB).ToList(); Look at the code

Comment: Your `ToList()` is in the wrong place, you need the `ToList()` to be called from the `Where` result, not from the `Contains` result.  `context.A.Where(x=> x.MyCollection.Contains(myB)).ToList()` is what you want.

Comment: Yeah, and it still doesn't work. "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains"

Comment: See this (in response to your error): http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069820/507793

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
public class A
{
    public List<B> MyCollection{get; set;}
}

public class B
{
     public string Id;
}

void Main()
{

    // this is what you're searching for
    var myB = new B{Id="1"};


    // here are some A objects to put in your collection
    A a1 = new A();
    a1.MyCollection = new List<B>();
    A a2 = new A();
    a2.MyCollection = new List<B> { myB };
    A a3 = new A();
    a3.MyCollection = new List<B> { new B {Id="1"}};


    // here's a List that represents your context.A
    List<A> contextA = new List<A> {a1, a2, a3};


    // here's your actual search. results has a count of 1
    var results = contextA.Where( x=> x.MyCollection.Contains(myB));
    Console.WriteLine(results.Count()); 
}
```

Note that this only finds a2, because you literally put the object "myB" in there. It does not find a3, which is a new object created with the same id.

If you wanted to find both a2 and a3, you'd probably want to change the Where to something like this:

```
var results = contextA.Where( x=> x.MyCollection.Any(b => b.Id == myB.Id));
```

Comment: It work's, because you operate on List. Sorry, I didn't mention I work on DbSet still " LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains " error

Comment: @7h4ro3: The last line in Lily's post is the correct answer. Using `Contains` for your query is wrong and `Any` is the correct way. `Contains` performs a comparison by object reference identity but EF and the database manage identity by a key, hence you need to use a key property (`Id`) to compare.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ans = from b in context.A.MyCollection
          where b.Id == 1
          select b;
```

or

```
var ans = context.A.MyCollection.Where(b => b.Id == 1);
```

Comment: Just to be clear. A doesn't have field "Id". I need to get from database context A elements which have in their field "MyCollection" specified element B

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
context.A.MyCollection.Where( x= > x.Id == myB.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: class A doesn't have field Id

Comment: great, forgot to write MyCollection :)