# Can I get string.Contains to return false?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
string s = "123,12346";

bool b = s.Contains("1234");
```

The above returns true, but is there a way to return false.  I have already done something like:

```
string[] s = {"123","12346"};

bool b = s.Contians("1234");
```

The above works, but I can't use the above in a contains expression with `LINQ-To-Entities` because it does not like Contains in `pre EF 4.0`.

I have an extension method which behaves like a `SQL IN` clause, but I need to explicitly type the parameters when I use it, I am not sure what to put between the brackets:

```
predicate = predicate(x=> WhereIn<>(x.Id, Ids));
```

`x.Id is a string and Ids is a string` as well.  If I put `WhereIn<string,string>`, it complains that `Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type ObjectQuery<string>`

`predicate` comes from the `PredicateBuilder`: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: The database schema obviously needs fixing. "x,y,z" in one column is wrong.

Comment: You don't want string.Contains to return false. You want to give a more accurate description of what you actually hope to achieve. string.Contains returning false isn't it.

Comment: I didn't vote down, but maybe you should clarify why "123,12346" should return false. Should it only return true in case of "123,1234" for example?

Comment: @JohnWillemse - I know that it is supposed to return true, the only problem I have is that once I convert it to an array, I can't use it with LINQ-To-Entities.

Comment: think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: @Mr.  - That is the extension method I am using, but when I do predicate = predicate.And(x=> WhereIn(x.Id,Ids), it wants me to specify TEntity and TValue explicity between in WhereIn<>, I am just not sure what.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/374703/728314 like this one?

Comment: How about this one? `",123,12346,".Contains(",1234,")`

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
string searchString = "123,12346";
bool b = sep(searchString,",").Contains("1234");

//Returns this string before ","
public static string sep(string s,string delimiter)
{
   int indx = s.IndexOf(delimiter);
   if (indx >0)
   {
      return s.Substring(0, indx);
   }
   return "";
}
```

Comment: That's going to check only the first item in a list of unknown length.  This does _not_ solve the question.

Comment: I can't tell how this is supposed to answer the question - you throw away all of the string after the first comma, or return an empty string if there's no comma.  This would still return `true` for `"123456,123"` (which I believe the OP would not want), and would return false for `"1234"` which also seems wrong.  And it looks as though you're trying (and failing) to re-implement `string.Split`.  Can you explain what this is supposed to be?

Comment: You are right, need iteration to catch all delimiters.