# Compare list of objects in linq query without using contain method using Entity Framework

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework

I have heard that using `contain` method degrades Entity Framework query performance.

My class file:

```
public partial class VendorInCategory
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int VendorId { get; set; }

        public virtual CategoryMaster CategoryMaster { get; set; }
        public virtual UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }
}
```

This is my query:

```
List<int> categoryIds = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count(); i++)
{
    categoryIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Items.ElementAt(i)));
}

var data = context.VendorInCategory
                  .Where(x => ((categoryIds).Contains(x.CategoryMaster.Id)) 
                   {
                        -------------------
                   }
```

Can anybody tell how do I compare this list without using `contain` keyword???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var l = from c in context.VendorInCategory
        join id in categoryIds on c.CategoryMaster.Id equals id into cid
        from id in cid.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {contextEntry = c, idEntry = id};

var data = (from d in l where d.idEntry != null select d.ContextEntry).ToList();
```

The first part joins the two, setting `idEntry` to null if there is no entry found. The second part retrives all of the `VendorInCategory` items from the context where `CategoryMaster.Id` exists in `categoryIds`.

Comment: i dont want to write query in this form.i want to write projection query only like i have written the query

Comment: Your question is marked with `linq` which is what this is. I'm not sure exactly how this will map to methods. But I use this same format for my ETL and it will process 100,000+ entries in 0.1 sec on average.

Comment: plz check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/contains-workaround-using-linq-to-entities.can u plz try with my query????